# accidently used dd on the wrong drive

Tags: ubuntu, files, data-recovery, disk, dump

i was trying to make a bootable usb with disk dump command in ubuntu, but i typed the wrong device name and hit enter so it started the process on my external hard drive , but after a few seconds i realized i just did something retarded that i just destroyed my ex hdd which i used for important files and i cancelled the dd with ctrl+c,now my hdd is empty , and when i try to use it on my windows it asks to be formatted  , how can i get my files back ?

Comment: I suggest to create a copy of your hard disk (with `dd` to a new disk or to a file on a disk with enough space) and try `photorec`. It may find some of your old files. Files in the area you have overwritten  will be definitely lost.

Comment: "_how can i get my files back?_" - unfortunately probably unlikely unless you have a backup. If you don't have a backup, when you recover from this calamity I strongly recommend you set up an automatic regular backup process for your important data.

Comment: After _many seconds of dd_ do not expect to be able to recover a lot. But you can use testdisk. Try not to touch the drive further, whatever you do to try to recover the information should be done with the drive as read only. You can also use `nbd` with _copy on write_ if you have to try a solution that would mean changing the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you didn't wipe all the disk. I also assume that you stopped using your disk immediately to avoid overwriting your files.

Teskdisk will not work for you. Photorec may work. Scalpel will be good for your situation. I will explain two ways to use it, depending your resources and your tools.

First, I assume that you have another laptop/desktop with a linux OS and a SATA to USB converter. If these apply to you, for faster results, do the following.

1. Extract the disk from your laptop
2. Connect it via USB to another PC
3. Install the package scalpel
4. With your favourite editor (vi/vim/nano, etc) open the file /etc/scalpel/scalpel.conf and uncomment the preferred lines
5. Run the following command ( scalpel /dev/sdX# -o output ) which will scan your disk and find any selected file type that is not overwritten but it may find some corrupted files.

Secondly, I assume that you have a USB disk with a linux iso. This way is cheaper but slower. In that case, do the following.

1. Boot from the USB to the linux OS
2. Install the package scalpel
3. With your favourite editor (vi/vim/nano, etc) open the file /etc/scalpel/scalpel.conf and uncomment the preferred lines
4. Run the following command ( scalpel /dev/sdX# -o output ) which will scan your disk and find any selected file type that is not overwritten but it may find some corrupted files.

The folder named output will be in the path from which you ran the command scalpel. In the folder named output will be a  txt file named audit.txt and folders with the selected types you searched for and inside them the recovered files, many of which will be corrupted.

Wish you luck!

P.S: For mp4 is more difficult to find the files but you can google it for scalpel and with a lot of effort, you will find them using scalpel.

Comment: i tried scalpel on my ubuntu, the same that i used dd on, uncomment lines for documents and images , but after 4 hours of waiting , it says "Segmentation Fault" and leave me with a folder  and a text file in it  named "audit" and nothing else.

Comment: You have to use scalpel from another system and scan your hard disk without mounting it.

Comment: so i need to plug it into another pc and unmount it ? i will try it , thanks

Comment: just plug it to another pc with linux. See with fdisk -l the sdX and run scalpel to it.

Comment: it still didnt work , i tried scalpel on my brother's mint , this time i waited for 10 hours just to get the exact same error

Comment: I haven't encountered an issue like yours.

Comment: i fixed it ! , i just tried chkdsk on my windows and it fixes everything ! , i have not checked every single one of them yet , but it seems that all my folders and files have been restored